# Sending Push notification to a URL instead of App

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to send a push message from an app, that when clicked directs to a URL instead of the app itself?

i.e. I want a push message to read "Please fill out this survey for us!" and when they click that push message, it will bring them to www.surveygizmo.com

Comment: Have a webview in your app which is loaded with that URL when that push notification is opened. Better yet use this: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/svwebviewcontroller and you dont even have to create a webview

Comment: @RyanG, thanks! How come this is easier than a webview?

Comment: Do you mean the link I posted? If you'd like you can make your own "WebBrowser" view controller with all of the basic buttons (back, forward, refresh etc..) But what I posted is a WebBrowser class that someone already created that you can drag into your app and use with only a couple lines of code. I use it in one of my apps and it works very nice. It also allows the users to "Open In Safari" if they want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do that. When the user clicks on a push it will open the app but you may be able to do something similar to your intended goal.

Send a json payload with your push and when your app is opened by the push you can read what you pass in and handle it. This can make it so you are able to have your app opened and according to what is passed in through the push redirect the app to a web page. Whether or not this goes against any guideline is up to you to figure out.